# Bounds for the Fourier transform of characteristic functions on $\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z}$ supported on large sets

Tags: fourier-analysis, analytic-number-theory, additive-combinatorics

Suppose $A \subseteq \mathbb{Z}_N := \mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z}$ with $|A| \geq N/2$. Let 
$$
\hat{A}(h) := \sum_{a \in A} e_N(ha),
$$
where $e_N(x) := e^{2\pi i x/N}$. Clearly $|\hat{A}(h)| \leq |A|$ for each $h$.

**Question:** Is it true that 
$$
S := \sum_{h=1}^{N-1} \left| \hat{A}(h) \right|
$$
is smaller than the trivial bound $N|A|$? I feel the large size of $A$ should imply greater cancellation in the sum. Perhaps one can show that $|S| \leq N \log N$ or so?

Comment: $\hat{A}(h)$ is called the [DFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform) of the vector $1_{a \in A}$

Answer (score 2):

Yes. By Cauchy's inequality,
\begin{align*}
(S+\#A)^2 = \bigg( \sum_{h=0}^{N-1} |\hat A(h)| \bigg)^2 &\le \bigg( \sum_{h=0}^{N-1} |\hat A(h)|^2 \bigg) \bigg( \sum_{h=0}^{N-1} 1^2 \bigg) \\
&= N \sum_{h=0}^{N-1} |\hat A(h)|^2 \\
&= N^2 \sum_{a\in A} 1^2 = N^2 \#A,
\end{align*}
where the last line follows by [Plancherel's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform#The_Plancherel_theorem_and_Parseval.27s_theorem) applied to $x_a = 1$ if $a\in A$ and $x_a=0$ otherwise. Therefore
$$
S \le N\sqrt{\#A} - \#A.
$$

Comment: Thank you very much Greg. I notice the proof does not make use of $A$ being large. Perhaps one could do a bit better for such sets? I imagine one could argue that if such an $A$ has too many gaps (meaning intervals $(b, c) \cap A = \emptyset$), then $A$ must also contain many intervals/runs of $\mathbb{Z}_N$ (since $A$ has large density; the gaps and the runs should balance out). Perhaps this might help in reducing the $\sqrt{\#A}$ factor above? Thanks again.

Comment: I'm not sure that's the case. For example, $A$ could have size $N/3$ and have a gap of size $N/3$ yet not contain any consecutive elements at all.

Comment: Hmm, if $\#A \geq N/2$ and it does not contain any intervals, then I believe it is an arithmetic progression with common difference $2$. Otherwise I think it should have intervals. But regardless perhaps one could try covering most of such an $A$ with arithmetic progressions? Yes, it's very hand-wavy..